# Where can I find checksums to verify the download of 12.04 alternate amd 64

Tags: 10.04, downloads

I would like to verify the ubuntu alternate install CD image I've downloaded via torrent. Where can I find the md5 checksums on the Ubuntu home page? Are they available via the site menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can view Ubuntu 12.04 Checksums in here

http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/

And for other releases in here

http://releases.ubuntu.com